# Rails 4 image_tag not working with fingerprints images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

My app wokring fine on local but on production it not showing images after compiling and digestion of assets.

Here is my code

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/v1/sale.png" %>
```

folder structure
**app/assets/images/v1/sale.png**

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the asset pipeline documentation (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) if you use absolute path it won't be resolved, but if you use the relative path under `/assets`, then the method will return a correctly fingerprinted url.

With absolute path:

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/v1/sale.png" %>

=> <img src="/assets/v1/sale.png"/>
```

With relative path:

```
<%= image_tag "v1/sale.png" %>

=> <img src="/assets/v1/sale-4dd5b109ee3439da54f5bdfd78a80473.png"/>
```